# a 3D cone object in XAML

Tags: xaml

I want to create a 3D cone object in XAML C#.
Could you help me to do, please.

Regards

Can

Answer (score 0):

Charles Petzold wrote an [article describing how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163449.aspx).

It shows how to make a cylinder (and cone), plus add material and texture information.